# Connect Wowza streaming engine to Google CDN

Tags: google-cloud-cdn

I would like to ask how to distribute the Wowza live stream video content to Google CDN to enable faster access. I saw Wowza has published the way to do it for Akamai and other network but not Google CDN. Google also pointed out it is possible, but i dont know how to setup http://gcp.solutions/diagram/Live%20Streaming. Could anyone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is already documented in WOWZA´s site describing all the steps on [How to set up Wowza Streaming Engine on Google Cloud Platform](https://www.wowza.com/docs/set-up-wowza-streaming-engine-on-google-cloud-platform).

Roughly, the steps are as follows:

Step#1 Add the Wowza Streaming Engine image to GCP

Navigation menu--> Compute Engine --> Images-->Create Image

a) Give your image a name and a description. The image name must be unique in your project's collection of images. The description is optional.

b) In Source, select Cloud Storage file.

c) In Cloud Storage file, enter wowzamediasystems/wse/WowzaStreamingEngine-4.7.6-byol-20180809.image.tar.gz.

Step#2 Add the firewall rule using the console
Step#3 Create and launch a Google Compute Engine instance

Details of these steps and additional clarification can be found in [Wowzaś site](https://www.wowza.com/docs/set-up-wowza-streaming-engine-on-google-cloud-platform)

The pre-configured Streaming Engine image runs Wowza Streaming Engine™ [media server software version 4.7.6.](https://www.wowza.com/docs/wowza-streaming-engine-4-7-6-release-notes)

Comment: Hi Nur. I am asking about the Google CDN, not how to deploy Wowza engine on Google compute engine.

Comment: I found this document on [Media & Entertainment Solutions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/media-entertainment/) discussing similar architecture, which you might find useful. However, this [combine the scale of Google Cloud infrastructure and performance of Anvato’s live streaming functionality](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/media-entertainment/architecture/live-streaming/).